# select child tag by value and double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I have several tags with the class `i11` all with child tags of class `i15`, I need to select a specific one of these child tags with a value `folder` (an unknown variable).
To better explain here's ahtml code snippet:

```
<div class = "i11">
  <input type = "text"
         class = "i15"
         style = "display: none;" />
  <input type = "text"
         class = "i16"
         style = "display: none;" />
  //other non-relevant html fields
</div>
//code above repeated 'x' amount of times
```

I have a context menu with an option that when it's selected it triggers a function and stores the value of the clicked `i11`'s `i15` value, I then need to select that specific `i15` in the function, I cannot set individual id's since there can be any number of these `i11` divs and are dynamically created.

The code I tried to select it was:

```
function a25() {
  var folder = $('#iFO').val();
  if (('.i11').children('.i15').val() == folder) {
    $(this).dblclick();
    console.log('yay!');
  } else {
    console.log("nothing :(");
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I need to select the ELEMENT or parent element itself not the value of the element by using the value retrieved and stored in `folder`, then trigger the double click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a class selector, even if only 1 element is selected, you'll get an array back, wrapped in a jQuery wrapper object. Hence, you'll need to get the element itself like so:

```
$('.i11').children('.i15').get(0).val() == folder//etc...
```

also, if there are multiple children with the same class (which is highly likely since you're not using id's) try looping through the children:

```
$(parentElement).children('.i15').each(function()
{
    if ($(this).val() === folder)
    {
        console.log($(this));// || console.log($(this).closest('.i11'));
    }
});
```

Another thing worth trying is explicitly triggering bound events and their handlers. Instead of doing `$(this).dblclick();` try `$(this).trigger('dblclick');`. 
hope this helps... though I might have misunderstood your question all together... if so: feel free to let me know

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your requirements properly, try this:

```
function a25() {
    var folder = $('#iFO').val();
    var $el = $('.i11').children('.i15');
    if ($el.val() == folder) {
        $el.select();
        console.log('yay!');
    } 
    else {
        console.log("nothing :(");
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working, but the tag needs to be double clicked, not selected, I tried it using what you've posted and with `.dblclick`
ps. you missed `$` from `$('.i11')`

Comment: Fixed. I thought you said you needed to select the text in the input? Why would you need to double click on a textbox?

Comment: no no, not select the text, select the element (tag), when `folder` is the value, double clicking the element triggers a function previously binded to the element.